# Date as variable in date_range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe ordered by date (asc). I would like to find the missing dates in this data frame

```
max_date = df['date'].tail(1)
min_date = df['date'].head(1)

missing_dates = pd.date_range( start= min_date, end= max_date).difference(df.index)
```

When trying to pass the dates as variables to the pd.date_range I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert input [0   2021-07-31 Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp
```

If I were to modify the missing_dates line and fix the dates:

```
missing_dates = pd.date_range( start= '2021-07-31', end= '2022-04-19').difference(df.index)
```

Then the code outputs the missing dates. How can I pass the variable to the pd.date_range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df['date'].tail(1)` returns a Series, you can use [`item()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html) to get the first value.

```py
max_date = df['date'].tail(1).item()
min_date = df['date'].head(1).item()
```